# Добавление в список после элемента заданной позиции

Tags: c++, список, структуры-данных

Есть у меня класс `List`:

```
class List //Класс Список
{
private:
    data *Head; //Указатель на последний активный элемент или просто голова списка
public:
    List(); 
    ~List(); 
    void Add(int x); 
    void Show(); 
    void addAfter(int x, int pos);
};
```

`data` - моя структура:

```
struct data 
{
    long int x; 
    data *Next; 
};
```

Объект своего класса использую как список. Функции добавления(Add) и вывода(Show) работают, пытаюсь довести до ума функцию, которая будет добавлять элемент по указанной позиции
Получилось вот это:

```
void List::addAfter(int x, int pos)
{
    data *temp = new data;
    int number = 0;
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        data *beg = temp; //запоминаем текущее состояние списка
        do //считаем сколько у нас в списке всего элементов
        {
            ++number;
            temp = temp->Next;
        }while(temp != NULL);
        if(pos > number) //если указанный номер позиции превышает кол-во элементов в списке
        {
            cout<<"Invalid position"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = beg; //откатываем список в исходное состояние 
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if(pos == i)
            {
                data *n_temp = new data;
                n_temp->x = x;
                n_temp->Next = temp->Next;
                temp->Next = n_temp;
            }
            else
                temp = temp->Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Ну, и собственно, функция не работает, и хотелось бы обратного
Путаюсь я в этой теме, не подскажите что у меня не так и что стоит изменить?

Comment: `data *temp = new data;` — ошибка здесь.

Comment: @Squidward, а что тут не так?

Comment: Что код в этой строке делает и зачем? Что он должен делать?

Comment: @Squidward, Спасибо, я понял в чём была моя ошибка, теперь всё работает